# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, iis-express

when i transported my application (using windows authentication)

```
User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
```

like above.

Throw error in iis but It works well in local.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

i enabled windows authentication. Where i am wrong?

Comment: Well the error seems to be clear enough. You try to get the second element of the Split() result, but if Split() function does not return anything then it will produce the IndexOutOfRangeException. Check if the result of Split() does return anything.

Comment: debug your app and you'll notice that your users name simply has no slash and thus `Split` will just provide an array with only a single element - the entire name. However as array-indices are zero-based, you need to use `Split(...)[0]` to access it.

Comment: its give me my username in  visual studio. i checked it. But after i published app to iis it throw error. If i dont use split. User.Identity.Name  its give me domain/username. But i  just  want to username.

Comment: But you split using `\ `, not with `/`.

Comment: so i need use it like this ? txt_Username.Text = User.Identity.Name.Split(...)[0];

Comment: no, like `Split('/')`.

Comment: sorry, didnt work.. Maybe i am wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only index you're using is 1 so, if that's out of range, then there must only be one element in your array, which means that there are no slashes in the input. What you want is the last element in the array, whether there is one or two elements, so use `User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last()` instead.

Comment: Error CS1061 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no accessible extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Suisenra, it is the [`Enumerable.Last`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-last-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) extension method, so you need to have referenced the appropriate assembly and imported the appropriate namespace. That's usually done by default but, if it wasn't or you removed it, you can add it in.

Comment: @Suisenra, mind you, it looks like this answer may be unnecessary, given that your comment on the question seems to suggest that you were specifying to split on a character that you didn't actually want to split on.

Comment: sorry, i am not good at it. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Maybe i should write again. My code is work well in local but when i publish it and work iis it is throw error.. and your last comment i dont understand it. I am really difficult station...

Comment: now. i tried split['\\'].Last(); but didnt give me username.

Comment: @Suisenra, gee, if only there was a way for us to know what it did give. I just can't think of anything.

Comment: well, i want to select to textbox from Windows Authentication. You give me another example. I can use it. Because i need it and it didnt work iis .  
(User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];)

Comment: when i use your split['\\'].Last();  textbox is empty. User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1]; give me my username. But it didnt work iis.. :(

Comment: @Suisenra, firstly, please tell me that you didn't just use `Split('\\').Last()` and nothing else. The point was you were supposed to use that instead of `Split('\\')[1]`. You still need to use the rest. Secondly, what `TextBox`? There's nothing in your question about a `TextBox`.

Comment: Textbox.Text=Split('\\')[1] . I just want to see in text box my username.

Comment: @Suisenra, good lord! I didn't think we'd have to wipe your nose too. Why would you think that you could get the user name back from that? Where are you putting anything useful into it. I already told you what to do. Are you not reading? Let me spell it out: `Textbox.Text = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();`.

Comment: yess you are amazing ! I told you more time but you just look down. My problem in IIS and i solved it. It working well and thank you for your help.. I disabled all  Authentication except for Windows  Authentication.